# Azure Pipelines variable ${{ variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] }} is always empty on a specific pipeline

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using the following setup for 2 different pipelines that target two different github repositories:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: windows-2022

variables:
  - group: shared-variables  # needed for the github access token which is used to create new releases in github

  - name: is_from_fork # its vital to use the notation variables['x'] for the environment variables below    if we use variables.x the value will be evaluated as empty!
    value: ${{ eq(variables['System.PullRequest.IsFork'], 'True') }}

  - name: has_green_build_reason
    value: ${{ in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest', 'Manual', 'Schedule', 'BuildCompletion', 'ResourceTrigger') }}

  - name: is_triggered_from_central_branches
    value: ${{ in(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main', 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/develop') }}

  - name: commit_message
    value: ${{ variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] }}

  - name: contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message
    value: ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], '[build]') }}

  - name: should_build
    ${{ if          eq(variables.is_from_fork, True)                              }}: # order   must be checked first
      value: 'No [is from fork]' # we want to explicitly disable any and all activity related to 3rd party forks in github
    ${{ elseif      eq(variables.has_green_build_reason, True)                    }}:
      value: 'Yes [has green build reason]'
    ${{ elseif      eq(variables.is_triggered_from_central_branches, True)        }}:
      value: 'Yes [is triggered from central branches]'
    ${{ else }}:
        value: 'Yes [temporary workaround for the fact that the commit message is not available in the build agent]'
#    ${{ elseif      eq(variables.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message, True)  }}:
#      value: 'Yes [contains build keyword in commit message]'
#    ${{ else }}:
#      value: 'No [humdrum feature branch commit]'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/develop

jobs:

  - job: 'Skip_Build'
    condition: ${{ startsWith(variables.should_build, 'No ') }}
    displayName: "Should we auto-build? ... ${{ variables.should_build }}     (is_from_fork=__${{ variables.is_from_fork }}__ ** has_green_build_reason=__${{ variables.has_green_build_reason }}__ ** is_triggered_from_central_branches=__${{ variables.is_triggered_from_central_branches }}__ ** contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message=__${{ variables.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message }}__ ** IsFork=__${{ variables['System.PullRequest.IsFork'] }}__ ** Build.Reason=__${{ variables['Build.Reason'] }}__ ** SourceBranch=__${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}__ ** SourceVersionMessage=__${{ variables.commit_message }}__)"
    steps:
      - checkout: none # keep this   otherwise it will make a full checkout of the repo unnecessarily
        displayName: '(Skipping checkout completely ...)'
      - script: 'echo "##vso[task.complete result=SucceededWithIssues;]Build skipped because this is a PR coming from a fork or because this is from a feature branch in which the latest commit message doesnt contain the keyword [build]"'
        displayName: '(Set Warning-Icon ... )'

  - job: 'Build'
    condition: ${{ startsWith(variables.should_build, 'Yes ') }}
    displayName: 'Build Agent'
    steps:

      - checkout: self
        fetchTags: true
        #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch
        fetchDepth: 0
        persistCredentials: true

      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Install NuGet'
        inputs:
          checkLatest: true
[...]
```

In the first pipeline the commit_message holds the latest commit-message. But in the second pipeline this variable is always empty no matter what. Both pipelines get triggered automatically every time I commit to their respective repositories.

I can't understand something like this is even possible.

Every single one of the settings related to these two pipelines are exactly the same. Right down to the connection I'm using to connect to github.

I also checked the settings in github but I couldn't spot anything significant there either. Is there some particular setting I should track down?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

Based on your update, I could reproduce the issue with the **minimal** YAML sample below and discovered that the variable `Build.SourceVersionMessage` only worked in **template expression** with `IndividualCI` trigger; when the pipeline was triggered `BatchedCI`, its value could not be expanded in **template expression**(`${ expression }`) or runtime expression (`$[ expression ]`)in job condition (`contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], '[build]')`) returns `Null`).

```
trigger:
# - main # Build.SourceVersionMessage workS in template expressions with IndividualCI trigger
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: windows-2022
variables:
  - name: commit_message
    value: ${{ variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] }}
  - name: contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message
    value: ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], '[build]') }}
  - name: should_build
    ${{ if      eq(variables.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message, True)  }}:
      value: 'Yes [contains build keyword in commit message]'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: 'No [humdrum feature branch commit]'

jobs:
- job: 'Skip_Build'
  condition: startsWith(variables.should_build, 'No ')
  displayName: "Should we auto-build? ... ${{ variables.should_build }}     (contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message=__${{ variables.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message }}__** SourceVersionMessage=__${{ variables.commit_message }}__)"
  steps:
  - checkout: none # keep this   otherwise it will make a full checkout of the repo unnecessarily
    displayName: '(Skipping checkout completely ...)'
  - script: |
      echo "BuildReason ... ${{ variables['Build.Reason'] }}"
      echo "SourceVersionMessage ... ${{ variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] }}"
      echo "contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message ... ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], '[build]') }}"
      echo "Should we auto-build? ... ${{ variables.should_build }}
- job: 'Build'
  condition: startsWith(variables['should_build'], 'Yes ')
  displayName: 'Build Agent'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchTags: true
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch
    fetchDepth: 0
    persistCredentials: true
  - script: |
      echo "BuildReason ... ${{ variables['Build.Reason'] }}"
      echo "SourceVersionMessage ... ${{ variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] }}"
      echo "contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message ... ${{ contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], '[build]') }}"
      echo "Should we auto-build? ... ${{ variables.should_build }}
```

[image]

If possible, please test to change the trigger section to be like `trigger: - main` and see if `IndividualCI` trigger can mitigate the issue.
[image]

In addition, as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), the variable `Build.SourceVerionMessage` is **not** available in templates. However, you are using template expression/conditional insertions (`${if}` `${elseif}` and `{else}`) to generate/evaluate `Build.SourceVersionMessage`  `commit_message` and `should_build`.

In addition to avoid using template expression to generate `commit_message` based non-template-available variables, you may consider using output variables in an additional dependency job and to evaluate subsequent jobs' conditions based the output varaibles.

Here is a sample for your reference.

```
trigger:
# - main # Build.SourceVersionMessage workS in template expressions with IndividualCI trigger
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: windows-2022

jobs:
- job: OutputVarjob
  displayName: "Output varialbes to check if we should auto-build"
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "System.PullRequest.IsFork ...$(System.PullRequest.IsFork)"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=is_from_fork;isoutput=true]$(System.PullRequest.IsFork)"
      
      Write-Host "Build.Reason ... $(Build.Reason)"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=has_green_build_reason;isoutput=true]$(Build.Reason)"
      
      Write-Host "Build.SourceBranch ... $(Build.SourceBranch)"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=is_triggered_from_central_branches;isoutput=true]$(Build.SourceBranch)"
      
      Write-Host "Build.SourceVersionMessage ... $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message;isoutput=true]$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
    name: SetOutput
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "is_from_fork ... $(SetOutput.is_from_fork)"
      Write-Host "has_green_build_reason ... $(SetOutput.has_green_build_reason)"
      Write-Host "is_triggered_from_central_branches ... $(SetOutput.is_triggered_from_central_branches)"
      Write-Host "contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message ... $(SetOutput.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message)"
- job: 'Skip_Build'
  dependsOn: OutputVarjob
  variables:
    is_from_fork: $[ dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.is_from_fork'] ]
    has_green_build_reason: $[ in( dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.has_green_build_reason'], 'BatchedCI', 'PullRequest', 'Manual', 'Schedule', 'BuildCompletion', 'ResourceTrigger') ]
    is_triggered_from_central_branches: $[ in( dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.is_triggered_from_central_branches'], 'refs/heads/main', 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/develop') ]
    contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message: $[ contains(dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message'], 'build') ]
  condition: or( eq(variables['is_from_fork'], 'True'), eq(variables['has_green_build_reason'], 'False'), eq(variables['is_triggered_from_central_brancheseq'], 'False'), eq(variables['contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message'], 'False') )
  displayName: "Should we auto-build? ...No"
  steps:
  - checkout: none # keep this   otherwise it will make a full checkout of the repo unnecessarily
    displayName: '(Skipping checkout completely ...)'
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "is_from_fork ... $(is_from_fork)"
      Write-Host "has_green_build_reason ... $(has_green_build_reason)"
      Write-Host "is_triggered_from_central_branches ... $(is_triggered_from_central_branches)"
      Write-Host "contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message ... $(contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message)"
- job: 'Build'
  dependsOn: OutputVarjob
  variables:
    is_from_fork: $[ dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.is_from_fork'] ]
    has_green_build_reason: $[ in( dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.has_green_build_reason'], 'BatchedCI', 'PullRequest', 'Manual', 'Schedule', 'BuildCompletion', 'ResourceTrigger') ]
    is_triggered_from_central_branches: $[ in( dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.is_triggered_from_central_branches'], 'refs/heads/main', 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/develop') ]
    contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message: $[ contains(dependencies.OutputVarjob.outputs['SetOutput.contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message'], 'build') ]
  condition: or( eq(variables['is_from_fork'], 'False'), eq(variables['has_green_build_reason'], 'True'), eq(variables['is_triggered_from_central_brancheseq'], 'True'), eq(variables['contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message'], 'True') )
  displayName: 'Build Agent'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchTags: true
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch
    fetchDepth: 0
    persistCredentials: true
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "is_from_fork ... $(is_from_fork)"
      Write-Host "has_green_build_reason ... $(has_green_build_reason)"
      Write-Host "is_triggered_from_central_branches ... $(is_triggered_from_central_branches)"
      Write-Host "contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message ... $(contains_build_keyword_in_commit_message)"
```

[image]

---

Not sure under what circumstances you had observed the behavior, however, I managed to reproduce the issue with the simple YAML pipeline below in my GitHub repo when the pipeline was **manually** triggered, while the value of `commit_message` was populated if the pipeline was triggered by `CI`.

```
name: BuildId_$(Build.BuildId)_$(Build.Reason)_$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r)
trigger:
- main
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: windows-2022
variables:
- name: commit_message
  value: ${{ variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] }}
steps:
- powershell: |
    Write-Host $(commit_message)
```

[image]

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), it appears that `Build.SourceVersionMessage` is not populated during compile time (not available in templates `${}`)if the pipeline is not triggered by `CI`.
[image]

For this, you may test with macro syntax directly, by which I managed to expand the expected value in the task.

```
name: BuildId_$(Build.BuildId)_$(Build.Reason)_$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r)
trigger:
- main
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: windows-2022
variables:
- name: commit_message
  value: $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)
steps:
- powershell: |
    Write-Host $(commit_message)
```

[image]

If you encounter failure in evaluating the `commit_message` in compile/run time expressions or any other scenario, please specify your usage requirement.

Hope the information could help resolve your concerns.

Comment: Both pipelines are triggered automatically by Azure CI every time I commit. They are really plain run-of-the-mil pipelines. The first one behaves as intended in terms of the commit message and the second one does not - even though all of their settings are identical.

Comment: Does macro syntax in the second pipeline incur the same issue as well? Can you please share a minimum but complete pipeline to show how the `commit_message`is used or evaluated?

Comment: I updated the post per your request

Comment: Hi @XDS, I have updated the answer with more findings based on your latest edits. Hope the workaround may help.

Comment: That's a really nice detailed answer Alvin!