Merge automation in Azure DevOps
First, I am a newbie to automation, so excuse me for any errors.
We currently use Azure DevOps repo  (migrated from TFS). In DevOps, we have a 'main' repo. Typical work is, that the developer creates their branch, and once it is ready, they push their branch to the remote DevOps repo (e.g. git push -u origin itsp2187).
Once in DevOps, the developer will create a PR, and once this gets approved, the PR is completed (merged to the remote main branch).
What I would like to do is to be able to do something when the PR is merged in the DevOps main branch. I need to update an external database with info from the merged PR (e.g., the user who executed the PR merge, the date & time when this happened, the PR title, and any description if possible).
What kind of software should I look into to accomplish this? is this even possible? I hear Actions is used in Github, I hear pipelines and webhooks for Azure. Are these the same? Or is any of these or some other software the most appropriate for this need?

Note all of that info is already in the Git history once the PR is completed, as well as forever available in the AzDO PR history, so it seems a little strange to want to make a copy of that specific info and store it in a separate DB somewhere.

Hi TTT, just to address your comment. The idea is to have a database where all the update history can be queries and viewed at once. You say that all that info is already in the Git history. Is this queryable? can I query and produce a spreadsheet with all the maintenance history for every item?

Just look a the history of the main branch. On any machine with that repo, git fetch followed by git log origin/main should be enough. Perhaps git log --first-parent origin/main will help weed out most of the commits and if needed there are more options you can use to just show the PRs.

Solution 1:
When a PR is merged, there will be a default Commit message like  Merged PR xx: The pull request title in the commit history.

Note: If you use the solution and want to Customize merge commit message, please keep the key word Merged PR xx:

Based on this message, we can create a pipeline which will run only when the  Commit message ($(Build.SourceVersionMessage)) contains the key word Merged PR. In the pipeline, we use the REST API  Get Pull Request By Id in the PowerShell task.
The following is my test steps:

Create a Personal Access Token with Code permission.



Create a pipeline with the following yaml in the main branch.

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

jobs:
  - job: A
    condition: eq(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'Merged PR'), True)
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Set your Azure DevOps organization, project, repository information
          $organization = "your organization name"
          $project = "your project name"
          $repositoryId = "your repo name"  # repo name or repo id

          $token="$(PAT)"
          $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))

          # get pullRequestId from the $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)
          $string = "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
          $splitString = $string.Split(" ")
          $pullRequestId = $splitString[2].Replace(":", "")

          Write-Host "pullRequestId is $pullRequestId"
          
          # Invoke the REST API to get the pull request
          $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId"+"?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
          $uri 

          try {
              $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
              $Response | ConvertTO-Json
          } catch {
              Write-Host "Error retrieving infornation of Pull Request $pullRequestId : $_"
              exit 1
          }



Create a secret Variable named PAT with the Personal Access Token in the pipeline.


Save the pipeline.

When a Pull request is merged, the pipeline will get the pull request information in the PowerShell task. If the Commit message doesn't contain the key word Merged PR, the job will be skipped.




Now, you can add other database related tasks to update an external database with pull request information from the PowerShell task.

Solution 2:
You can use the webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines with the Pull request updated event.
Detailed steps:

Create an Incoming WebHook service connection



Create a Service hook web hook with Pull request updated event and choose Status changed.



The Request Url is "https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview". The WebHook Name is the one you set in the service connection.


Create a pipeline with the resource type webhooks. The pipeline will be triggered when the Pull request updated webhook event is received by the Incoming Webhook service connection and you can consume the payload data in the form of variables in your jobs.

Sample Yaml:
trigger: none
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: MyWebhookTrigger         ### Webhook name
      connection: MyWebhookConnection    ### Incoming webhook service connection name
      filters:
        - path: resource.status
          value: completed
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    ### JSON payload data is available in the form of ${{ parameters.<WebhookAlias>.<JSONPath>}}
    script: |
      Write-Host "user who executed the PR merge: ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.createdBy.displayName}}"
      Write-Host "creationDate:  ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.creationDate}}"
      Write-Host "closedDate:  ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.closedDate}}"
      Write-Host "PR title:  ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.title}}"
      Write-Host "description:  ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.description}}"
      


Test result:



Now, you can add other database related tasks to update an external database with the pull request information form the web hook.


Thank you so much. This is exactly the kind of info I was looking for.

I'm glad to hear it's helpful to you! Happy coding!

Hello Miao, From our remote azure repo, I tried to create a pipeline (selected 'starter pipeline' with just a simple 'hello world'), but I am getting a "TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request t update this branch". I don't get it. Of course this pipeline must be in the main branch, that is where it will be applied no?

Hi @user7221839, it seems your main branch has Branch policies.  You can't push changes directly to branches that have required branch policies unless you have permissions to bypass branch policies. Changes to these branches can be made only through pull requests.

If you choose the solution 1, the pipeline should be in the main branch.  You can add the yaml file to the main branch through pull request. If you choose the solution 2, the branch of the pipeline is not important as the target branch is set in the web hook, not in the pipeline.

Hi @Miao, I got my starter pipeline to run fine now (I had to submit that request to MS, and also set the 'default branch' for my yaml to be my feature branch).  I am now going thru your sample yaml (option 1). There is a line I don't understand: you define a variable to contain the REST API uri ($uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/pullRequests/$pullRequestId"+"?api-version=7.1-preview.1"), no problem there. But then in the next line you have only "$uri" (right before the try/catch block) . What does this do??

Hi @user7221839, this line will show the actual uri in the log. Just to check if the uri is correct when I test it. You can ignore this line. :)

Hi Miao, l created a PAT (called it "pipelinePAT"). Then, from my pipeline, I created a secret variable, called "pipelinePATsecret". So my equivalent line in the script (option1) would be  $token="$(pipelinePATsecret)". I am confused though: how are the two of them linked? you said "create a secret variable with the Personal Access token in your pipeline". Did you mean that when I created my secret variable I should've copied and pasted in there the value of my Personal Access Token I created before?? is that how they are linked?? Thank you

Hi @user7221839, Yes, you are correct. When creating the Personal Access Token (PAT), you can copy the PAT value. Then, when you create the secret variable, paste this PAT value into the secret variable value field.

Hi Miao, I got my first pipeline to work, for now just outputting the given PR info. I have done some minor adjustments, like adding batch, variable groups. I then tested and for some reason the pipeline was skipped. Even though the test PR had the 'Merged PR XXX:..." message. How can I post here the screenshot so you can see it, and the log that shows skipped?

Hi Miao, i figured why the pipeline condition was skipped. It turns out variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'] does not work when you have the "batch" entry in your pipeline. In this case the variable is null  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573434/azure-pipelines-variable-variablesbuild-sourceversionmessage-is-alway

Hi @user7221839, yes, thanks for your reminder. This is a disadvantage of this solution which I didn't realize before. Maybe you can try the second solution which is more stable.
